# TCPDF All Columns are not showing

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I'm creating a pdf file using PHP. In here i first create a HTML table with all contents i need to print on the PDF file. But on creating the pdf last 4 columns on the right side is missing. Its cropped off the remaining columns. Can anyone knows how to fix this issue?? I tried by changing the PDF format from "A4_Long" to "A5_Long". Still its not showing.

Answer (score 1):

as pdf file can not show scroll so it tries to print the most possible data of html on the pdf, the columns exceeds the width of the page are printed somewhere where it losts.

Now. How will you show all columns.

1. decrease the overall text size small enough to be read.
2. assign the column widths according to their data, if any column is having extra white space try to manage that space for the right columns which are disappearing due to page size.